# MVC Server Side VS MVC Client Side and RESTful APIs

Tags: php, javascript, rest, model-view-controller

I'm still relatively new to web 2.0, but as I immerse myself more and more terms such as MVC and RESTful keep popping up everywhere I go.  I have worked a bit with AngularJS and read up on other MVC javascript frameworks for the client side, but until recently I was unaware of anything outside of straight PHP for the server side.  I'm really trying to understand how MVC works on the server side and if I should implement an MVC PHP framework or go for something like node.js or GO which as I understand both follow the MVC model.  I suppose the biggest problem I'm having is trying to understand how an MVC client side application written in a javascript framework like backbone or angularjs would fit in with an MVC server architecture.  Also and this may be completely unrelated but how do RESTful APIs come into play with all of this?

Please understand my experience with server side programming extends to a PHP page that receives data from an ajax call, queries the database and returns the result as a JSON object.  I really don't even know the full potential of a strong backend or in what circumstances I would need anything more than what I've explained I've already done.  Sorry if this is a really silly question,  I'm just trying to understand and seperate my thought process when it comes to server side and client side programming and trying to understand the potential of using both effectively.

Thanks!

EDIT

I appreciate the Sarcasm.  Let me boil it down.  What is the difference between a server side MVC and a client side MVC and how do the 2 work together?

Comment: And what is your programming question? Do you want to borrow my Tamagotchi? It has MVC as well.

Comment: @hakre I can lend a unicorn if it helps.

Comment: See the edit sorry it wasn't clear before

Comment: @Jocelyn: Why not? I also heard that [Pigeons are strong on the backend with Web 2.0](http://www.google.com/technology/pigeonrank.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What is the difference between a server side MVC and a client side MVC and how do the 2 work together?

That is pretty straight forward (no sarcasm here). The one operates on the client the other on the server.

They normally do not really work together but are more independent to each other. For example, if you have a client side MVC you normally use the server-side to provide the data-source for it, do some bookkeeping like session management and hearbeat service. So on the server there most likely is not running a full blown MVC.

Comment: Okay that helps, I wasn't sure if I was missing the bennefits by utilizing a client side MVC and not both.  Thanks.